# unique used in nested subquery SQL plus

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to execute this code-

```
select
    T.course_id
from
    course_test T
where 
    unique(
        select
            R.course_id
        from
            section R
        where
            T.course_id = R.course_id and R.year=2009
    );
```

and it is giving missing expression in the `unique`.
So my question is is unique allowed in sql plus?

edit-I want to find all courses that were offered at most once in 2009

course-

```
course_id title dept_name 
BIO-101 intro to BIO bio
```

section-

```
course_id year
BIO-101 2009
```

will give answer as BIO-101 as the answer
NOTE-my queries are written in SQL plus and I want answer related to it only.I know this works in MySQL.

Comment: I have never seen a syntax like that in oracle. What are you to achieve? Give some sample data and expected output. Maybe you want to use `exists` instead of `unique`.

Comment: What is your query meant to do, exactly? What is the relationship between `course_test` and `section`? Can you post example schemas and test data and expected output?

Comment: @Dai added the needful

Comment: In SQL  condition doc there is not an UNIQUE operator  ...but what do you need  with UNIQUE  .. ?  returning a single rows? obtain the first row ?  ..  where condition applied  only if the subselect return only a row?  .. is not clear to me

Comment: That usage of `UNIQUE` is non-standard SQL - what do you think it does? Return a single row?

Comment: Any [Oracle SQL syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/index.html) will be the same in [SQL\*Plus](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqpug/SQL-Plus-quick-start.html) as in any other tool.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to find all courses that were offered at most once in 2009

You can do it by testing `COUNT` manually. I'm not familiar with Oracle and PL/SQL ("SQL Plus" is a program, not a language) so I can't say how `UNIQUE()` is meant to work, but here's how I'd do it (using standard SQL that works in all SQL-92-compliant databases):

```
SELECT
    courses.*
FROM
    courses
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            course_id
        FROM
            section
        WHERE
            year = 2009
        GROUP BY
            course_id
        HAVING
            COUNT(*) = 1
    ) AS courses_1_in_2009 ON courses_1_in_2009.course_id = courses.course_id
```

This works by using the inner subquery `` as a filter to select only courses that appeared only once in 2009, if you run it individually you'll see the results it gets:

```
SELECT
    course_id,
    COUNT(*) AS count_2009
FROM
    section
WHERE
    year = 2009
GROUP BY
    course_id
```

Then we can add the `HAVING` statement and remove the unneeded `count_2009` column to get the `course_id`s of the courses we're interested in:

```
SELECT
    course_id
FROM
    section
WHERE
    year = 2009
GROUP BY
    course_id
HAVING
    COUNT(*) = 1
```

Then perform an `INNER JOIN` with `courses` to get their actual names and other values to get the query I posted at the top.

Comment: I dont want to solve the query...I already how to..I am asking specifically about unique in sql plus using an example query

Comment: @ubuntu_noob . . . "I want to find all courses that were offered at most once in 2009".  This answers your question.  If you downvoted Dai, you should undo it.  If you specifically want to ask about the syntax for `unique`, then your question needs to be clearer.

Comment: @ubuntu_noob [SQL\*Plus](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqpug/SQL-Plus-quick-start.html) does not have a `UNIQUE` keyword. [SQL](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/index.html) does, but in a `SELECT` statement it means the same thing as [`DISTINCT`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/SELECT.html#d431384e2632). I'm not sure why you thought it would do something different.